# From nested tuples to edges of a binomial tree, in Python

Tags: python, algorithm, python-3.x, data-structures, tree

What is a quick way to convert a nested tuple structure (i.e. recombining binomial/binary tree) as

```
t = (4, (3, 5, (2, 4, 6, (1, 3, 5, 7))))
```

to the (ordered) tuple of edges

```
((4,3), (4,5),                               # step 1 edges
 (3,2), (3,4),  (5,4), (5,6),                # step 2 edges
 (2,1), (2,3),  (4,3), (4,5),  (6,5), (6,7)) # step 3 edges
```

Each node leads to a pair of child nodes, one below and one above the parent node. Thus, 4 leads to 3 and 5; 3 leads to 2 and 4; and so on.

The tuple `t` represents the following *binomial tree* structure

[image]

Comment: Emm.. You have built some weird data structure (as another your question states) and  want to extract its parts/edges/bricks back? What is your real problem?

Comment: Do you have any say in that data structure?  It appears to contain the rows of the DAG (columns, in the image you provided), and rows are naturally represented by a sequence like a `list`... so why is it nested instead of sequential?  A sequence of rows would be iterable without any unpacking required, and as a bonus would give you depth-first-search for free:  `for row in rows: if target in row: do_something(target)`.

Comment: Direction is of no importance, but edges are. I have not thought of bricks, but it may be relevant :) These tree-form transformations are driven by exploration of language and structure efficiencies (or limitations). Great comments!

Comment: If direction doesn't matter, what do those arrows represent?  That sure implies they are directed.  And trees are _always_ directed --- parent-of and child-of are _very_ different relationships.  (Technically, if a vertex can have multiple incoming arrows, it doesn't qualify as a "tree" at all, which is why I called it a DAG... which might also be wrong, depending on what your requirements _really_ are.)

Comment: The structure you're building looks like the [binomial options pricing model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_options_pricing_model#Method) from economics (also in the ["
tree-based equity option valuation" sidebar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lattice_model_%28finance%29#Equity_and_commodity_derivatives) of the "lattice model").  It is based on a similarly-misnamed "tree", and even suggests that "binomial" isn't just a typo for "binary". (I see it as a DAG used to represent a collection of polynomials... which suddenly makes a lot of sense.)  Is _this_ what you've been aiming for?

Comment: Yes, well noted, BOPM is, in fact, the basis for this data structure. The order in this tree is always in the same direction (from parent to child), so the arrows may be omitted. The edges are non-directional and carry complete information about the original structure. Thanks for noting.

Comment: "The order in this tree is always in the same direction  [...]  The edges are non-directional"  --- These two statements contradict each other.  Your data structure is a specialized [_directed_ acyclic graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_graph) (or DAG).  _Humans_ who are already familiar with BOPM know that the graph is directed, and can assume the direction itself from the way it's drawn; _computers_ don't know any of that (nor do Stack Overflow readers), and must be told.

Comment: A suggestion:  It sounds like the financial world uses words like "tree" and "binomial" (and probably "directed") differently.  These words already have very precise meanings in computer science.  Since Stack Overflow is mostly programmers, you'll be better off using the computer science definitions, or at least emphasizing that you're using the world-of-finance meanings (and linking to things like the Wikipedia BOPM article in your questions).  Without that kind of shared background, your readers will keep misunderstanding what you're trying to do and why.

Comment: I agree, "binomial" should have been "binary" and arrows may be suggestive. Any extra information about BOPM will only complicate the question. I hope you'd agree. Thanks for comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def g(t):
    res = []
    for i,x in enumerate(t[:-1]):
        res.append((x, t[-1][i]))
        res.append((x, t[-1][i+1]))
    return res

def h(t):
    if isinstance((t[-1]), tuple):
        return g(t) + h(t[-1])
    else:
        return []

t = (4, (3, 5, (2, 4, 6, (1, 3, 5, 7))))
print h(t)
```

Comment: Why not give those functions names that indicate what they do?

Comment: It was one of the amazon interview questions :(